# Find the length of the shortest path from the point (3,5) to the point (8,2) that touches the x-axis and also touches the y-axis

Tags: graphing-functions

My problem is that I can't create a line that passes through both points AND is the shortest path AND touches both axis lines.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: fix one point and look at paths from this point to a reflection of the other in both axes (you need to cross both) - eg from (3,5) to (-8,-2)

Think about how the proof by reflection works for one mirror, and apply it with two.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  A path can be a sequence of segments.  You can go from $(8,2)$ to $(0,y)$ to $(x,0)$ to $(3,5)$  Calculate the length of each segment, add them to get the total path length.  Then you can differentiate to find the minimum in each variable-you will get two equations in two unknowns.  Or, you can remember angle of incidence=angle of reflection and use that.  I don't warrant that this you should go to the $y$ axis first, but it looks likely.

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers here are not good enough. The correct way to do it is as follows:

- Reflect $P(3,5)$ about the $y$ axis to obtain $P'$ and reflect $Q(8,2)$ about the $x$ axis to obtain $Q'$.
- Now consider points $R$ and $S$ on $y$ and $x$ axes respectively.
- Then path length$= PR+RS+SQ= P'R+RS+SQ'$. 
  So, this always represents a path from $P'$ to $Q'$.
- To minimize this path length, a straight line joining $P'$ and $Q'$ would suffice.
- Hence you can determine the coordinates of $R$ and $S$.
- However, take another case whereby you reflect $P$ about the $x$ axis and $Q$ about the $y$ axis.

Follow the above steps and calculate the path length.

Compare the two lengths and consider the minimum length.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: i am surprised people are downvoting this answer, even though this is the most ingenious answer there is.

Answer (score 2):

You follow path of light.

First point is (3,5), then comes (0,a) and (b,0) and finally (8,2).
Line equation for the first segment is $y=\frac{5-a}{3}x+a$.
Line equation for the second segment is $y=-\frac{a}{b}x+a$.
Line equation for the third (last) segment is $y=\frac{2}{8-b}x-\frac{2b}{8-b}$.

Because it's reflection in both cases, $k_1=-k_2$ and $k_2=-k_3$:
1) $\frac{5-a}{3}=-\left( -\frac{a}{b}\right)$
2) $-\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{2}{8-b}$

Solve it!

Comment: Better see answer of Mark Bennet.